# Is $d(x,y)=|\log(x/y)|$ the only metric that makes $(\mathbb{R}_+,d)$ complete?

Tags: metric-spaces, real-numbers, complete-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}_+$ be the set of strictly positive real numbers. Consider the following distance between elements of $\mathbb{R}_+$
$$
d(x,y)=\left|\log\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right|.
$$

It is easy to prove that this distance makes the metric space $(\mathbb{R}_+,d)$ complete. But is $d$ the *unique* distance with this property?

Comment: The discrete metric given by $d(x, y) = 1$ if $x \neq y$ also makes $\Bbb R_+$ complete.

Comment: A bit trivial, but also any metric of the form $d(x,y)=K|\log(x/y)|$, where $K>0$.

Comment: $|x-y|+ |\frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{y}|$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take any continuous, injective function $f:\Bbb R_+\to \Bbb R$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$ (or vice versa). Then $d(x, y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$ will give a complete metric space. In fact, it will be isometric, via $f$, to $\Bbb R$ with the standard metric.

Your example uses $f(x) = \log(x)$, and orangeskid in the comment above uses $f(x) = x - \frac1x$.

Comment: Nice answer! Note that I used the imbedding $x \mapsto (x, \frac{1}{x})$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is another standard trick. Thanks for the mention.

Comment: @orangeskid If you use the standard metric on $\Bbb R^2$, shouldn't you have gotten $\sqrt{|x-y|^2+ |\frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{y}|^2}$ instead? At any rate, taxicab metric is also valid.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it was just easier to write.  If we further project the hyperbola piece onto the second diagonal we do get your metric now.

Comment: Many thanks for the complete answer! I was wondering what happens if we further require that $(\mathbb{R}_+,d)$ is a *geodesically* complete metric space...

Comment: Sir, is there is proof of "Take any continuous, injective function $f:\Bbb R_+\to \Bbb R$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$ (or vice versa). Then $d(x, y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$ will give a complete metric space" I had just proved this for $f(x)=log(x)$. But, how to prove it for general $f$.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi As I said, $f$ is an isometry between $(\Bbb R_+,d)$ and $\Bbb R$ with the standard metric. This follows almost directly from $d(x, y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$. And since $\Bbb R$ with the standard metric is complete, $(\Bbb R_+,d)$ is complete.

Comment: Sir, I think, condition $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$ (or vice versa) is needed to make $f$ bijective function (from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $\mathbb{R}$) am i correct?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I did only say "injective", but yeah. If we say bijective (and continuous), we don't need to specify the limits.